# Как найти координаты точек пересечения двух окружностей в пространстве?

Tags: математика, геометрия, навигация

Имеется две окружности в пространстве, нормали к которым совпадают с двумя ортами косоугольной системы координат. Третий орт перпендикулярен к остальным. Уравнения окружностей задаются в эллиптических системах координат ({mu, nu1}; {mu, nu2}), базы которых связаны с двумя первыми ортами:
x1 = a * cosh(mu) * cos(nu1) 
r1 = a * sinh(mu) * sin(nu1) 
y1 = 0 
z1 = 0

z2 = b * cosh(mu) * cos(nu2) 
r2 = b * sinh(mu) * sin(nu2) 
y2 = 0 
x2 = 0

Имеется также угол пересечения первых двух ортов alpha.

Эти уравнения в трехмерном пространстве дают две окружности. Как можно найти координаты точек пересечения?

На рисунке представлено расположение поверхностей положения, получаемые в навигационной системе. Пересечение синей и зеленой поверхностей дают первую окружность. Пересечение красной и желтой - вторую. Учитывая, что поверхности получаются в результате определения навигационных параметров (mu, nu1, nu2) - считается что решение всегда существует, но не однозначно. Многозначность устраняется отделльно.
[image]

P.S.: Дело в том, что я на входе получаю разность дальностей между моей координатой и двумя точками, образующими одну базу - это дает мне гиперболоид, изображенный зеленым цветом. Точно также я получаю вторую разность дальностей, но уже до второй базы - это дает мне желтый гиперболоид (одна точка принадлежит одновременно двум базам и является началом системы координат). Таким образом можно определить линию моего местоположения, образованную пересечением двух гиперболоидов. Но в конечном итоге необходимо определить связь координат объекта и измеряемых параметров (двух разностей дальностей). Для этого мне требуется ввести третий параметр, которому будет соответствовать поверхность положения, которая при пересечении с уже найденной линией положения даст точку положения. Но она должна пересекаться под как можно более прямым углом к этой линии (для наивысшей точности оценки координат). Но как это сделать правильнее? Я решил, что разумно дополнить систему двух имеющихся разностей дальностей еще двумя суммами дальностей от моего местоположения до тех же точек. Это даст два эллипсоида, софокусных тем же гиперболоидам (т.е. ортогональных им).  Таким образом задача свелась к определению точек пересечения двух колец. Однако я уже сомневаюсь, что на правильном пути...

Comment: Запишите нормально уравнения окружностей (то, что написали вы - лично мне совершенно непонятно), и решайте систему...

Comment: хм.... для начала бы неплохо проверить, что они вообще пересекаются

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов А это будет ясно из того, имеются ли решения :)

Comment: Считается, что они пересекаются. Можно также предположить, что a=b.

Comment: @Harry, можно и так. Но в любом случае: для каждой окружности даны формулы двух координат их точек, а должна быть еще и третья.

Comment: хм....А почему a=b?

Comment: a,b - это длины баз эллиптических систем координат.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов дополнил систему дополнительными условиями

Comment: @ViktorLegkostup Как понимаю, **x, y, z** - координаты точек, судя по рисунку. Тогда что такое **r**?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов выходит,что r - радиус окружности

Comment: @ViktorLegkostup Радиус окружности не может быть переменной величиной.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104954/discussion-between---and-viktor-legkostup).